# The term is not recognized as cmdlet function script file or operable program ... in cmder / powershell

Tags: powershell, cmder

I use cmder, and created some aliases for powershell in user-profile.ps1 in cmder/config/user-profile.ps1.

The file looks like this

```
# Use this file to run your own startup commands
New-Alias subl "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
New-Alias mysql "D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.11\bin\mysql.exe"
New-Alias o Invoke-Item
New-Alias c Clear-Host
New-Alias hosts "subl $env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
New-Alias .. "cd .."
New-Alias www "cd d:\wamp\www"
```

And all aliases work properly except '..', 'www' and 'hosts'. When I write 'hosts', for example, it gives me an error like

```
The term "subl C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" is not recognized as cmdlet function script file or operable program
At line:1 char:1
+ hosts
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (subl C:\Windows...ivers\etc\hosts:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But, when I write in cmder 'subl C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', it works. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell, an Alias is a mapping to *a command* - not just to any kind of expression.

If you want `hosts` to open the hosts file in Sublime, define a function instead:

```
function hosts { subl $env:windir\System32\drivers\etc\hosts }
```

Same with `..` and `www`

```
function .. { cd .. }
function www { cd d:\wamp\www }
```